# JSDOC reference function not in a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

If I have two functions in (neither inside an explicit class) in the following structure

A/foo.ts

B/bar.ts

Where

bar.ts  has

```
export const happy()...
```

And foo.ts has

```
/** @see happy /*
```

How can I see the correct linkage to bar#happy?

I tried borrows and and alias to no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import the type only like the following snippet. `import type`s are removed when compiled to JavaScript so you're safe if this is not intended.

**foo.ts**

```js
import type { happy } from './bar'

/** @see happy */
```

[image]